Example of an Altlas for the torus
I would like to know if the following can be used as an atlas for the torus $ T^2 $.
Since $ T^2 $=$ S^1 \times S^1$ , then an atlas for the torus is given by the cartesian product of two atlases for the unit circle where my unit circle atlas is given by $$ \{((U_1,\phi_1),(U_2,\phi_2) \}$$
where $ U_1=S^1-\{(1,0)\} $ and $ U_2=S^1-\{(-1,0)\} $ with $ \phi_1: U_1 \rightarrow (0,2\pi)$ and $ \phi_2: U_2 \rightarrow (-\pi,\pi)$.
With inverse $ \phi^{-1}_{1}: \alpha \rightarrow (cos\alpha,sin\alpha) $ same for the the other one just changes the domain from $ ( 0,2\pi ) $ to $ ( -\pi,\pi ) $ .
So with this definitions my atlas for the torus can be constructed as
$$
\{(U_1 \times U_1 ,(\phi_1,\phi_1) ),(U_2 \times U_2 ,(\phi_2,\phi_2) ), (U_1 \times U_2 ,(\phi_1,\phi_2) )\}
$$
Is this a good atlas for the torus ? Or I have been sloppy ?
p.s
I checked that change of coordinates is smooth and indeed it is

If the transition maps are smooth, you just need to check that every point is in one of the 3 charts, and really based on how you've defined the charts, there is at most 4 cases to check.

yea I did that, so I can define the atlas in this way thank you

My suspicions were raised by the lack of symmetry of your atlas.
I asked myself, why did you leave out $(U_2 \times U_1,(\phi_2,\phi_1))$?
So I hunted for a point that does not lie in any of your charts (and made a few mistakes) and finally I found exactly one such point, namely the center point of the missing coordinate chart $(U_2 \times U_1,(\phi_2,\phi_1))$ which is the point
$$((1,0),(-1,0))
$$

Thank you !  So i guess I will need 4 chart to make it an atlas.

Sorry but I am still new to this stuff, could I define an atlas of torus as seen as a subset of $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ in the two dimensional case right? With inverse chart given by the usual parametrization?

That's a different question, and could perhaps be a different MSE post, with sufficient context.

Will do thanks.

@Lip: It is possible to make a 3-chart atlas for the torus, if you offset the charts from each other in the right way.
